# How to use temp table across multiple databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My script here iterate over all my DB with a certain name and collect a count. This works but my problem is I would like to merge all the results into on set so I can export at CSV or similar. Otherwise Lot of data to copy form the result view.

I tried to declare a @temp table, beginning of the file, and insert into this but it does not work. I suspect the call to each database is in a new connection and therefor it fails. Can I make an in memory table I can write back to then select all from this?

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200) 
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 
where name like '%_MSCRM%'

OPEN database_cursor 



FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = 'SELECT ' + '''' + @DB_Name + '''' + ' as Tenant, count(*) as Count  FROM [' + @DB_Name + '].[dbo].[si_RecruitBase]'
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command 

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried? And variable tables are ok, but you probably should create a #temp table instead. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for input. I cheated and used some powershell.

```
$SQLServer = $prod
$DatabaseNames = $List_of_DBS

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

foreach ($SQLDBName in $DatabaseNames) 
{
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"
    $SqlConnection.Open()
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

    $SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT count (*) from si_RecruitBase;"

    $result= $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
 
    $SqlConnection.Close()
 
    Write-output "Tenant: $SQLDBName has: " $result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without creating your own cursor.

```
-- Create a temp table to store the results
CREATE TABLE #Results(Tenant NVARCHAR(255), Amount INT)

-- use sp_MsForEachDb to loop over all databases
exec sp_MSForEachDb '
    -- Filter on your specific database
    IF ''?'' LIKE ''%_MSCRM%''
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Results(Tenant, Amount)
        SELECT  ''?''  as Tenant, count(*) as Count  FROM [?].[dbo].[si_RecruitBase]
    END
'

-- show the results
SELECT *
FROM #Results
```

Comment: Please don't use the undocumented and unreliable sp_MSForEachDb.  See https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb

Answer (score 0):

*Polite notice this answer contains "shameless" self promotion.*

---

Rather than use a `CURSOR` like you have here, I'm going to use a Stored Procedure I wrote a while back, [`sp_foreachdatabase`](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/), which uses a set based method to query each database, but also allows for additional functionality. The handy bit here will the injection of the name as a `sysname` and before and after statements. This results in something like this:

```
DECLARE @Command_Run nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @Databases dbo.objectlist;

INSERT INTO @Databases ([name])
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] LIKE '%[_]MSCRM%';

EXEC sp_foreachdatabase @Command = N'INSERT INTO #TentantCount (Tenant, [Count]) SELECT &, COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[si_RecruitBase];',
                        @Database_List = @Databases,
                        @Auto_Use = 1,
                        @Exit_On_Error = 0,
                        @Pre_Command = N'CREATE TABLE #TentantCount (Tenant sysname, [Count] int);',
                        @Post_Command = N'SELECT * FROM #TentantCount;',
                        @Command_Run = @Command_Run OUTPUT;

PRINT @Command_Run;
GO
```